# Xcode 9. Interface Builder. Installed checkmark is missing

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, xcode9

I would like to make a constraint inactive in IB. I used to always do that by unselecting **Installed** checkmark but it seems to be missing in Xcode 9. Take a look.

[image]

It should be beneath **Placeholder** row but as you see it's not there. Did Apple remove this feature? If so then is there an alternative? Or I just should enable it somewhere?

Comment: I am using XCode 9.2, and I see the `Installed checkmark` correctly.

Comment: Ok. Then it might be Xcode 9.0 bug.

Comment: No. Even in Xcode 9.2 I still see that the checkmark is missing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've figured it out. I had to select **Use Trait Variations** checkmark in the **File Inspector** and then **Installed** checkmark appeared